# I want to make it so file.write() only writes on that line if that line has nothing written on it

Tags: python, file

```
def password_generator():
    "code to generate a password here"
    file = open('/Users/benkollmar/Desktop/Projects/Passwords', 'w')
    file.write(password_sentence)
```

Every time I call this function it writes what I want in the new file on the first line but I want to add an if statement so it only writes on the line if that line is empty. And if that line is not empty write password_sentence on the next empty line.

Comment: Please *never* post pictures of code. Add the relevant code as text in your answer. In any case, seems to me like you want to open the file with `a` which appends at the end.

Comment: Sorry I've never posted to stack overflow before. I tried to type out the code but when I posted it the post formatted it wrong so I just screenshotted it.

Comment: To get it to be formatted properly you need to have 4 spaces behind every line of code

Comment: At the operating system level, files don't operate a line-at-a-time in the first place. Everything is in terms of byte offsets. You don't replace a line with a new line editing a file in-place; you can only replace specific bytes with (the same number of) other bytes. If you want to replace a "line" with a different line that's of a different length, you have to rewrite the entire rest of the file; so you **cannot** rewrite the first line of a file over and over without rewriting the whole file, unless that first line's length is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `with open()` because it automatically closes the file when your done.

You can see that I used `'a'` here. That means append, which means add to the end of the file. Finally, adding a `\n` at the end of your content forces anything appended after it later to be on a different line.

```
with open(passwordsFile, 'a') as file:
    file.write(password_scentence + '\n')
```

Comment: The OP wants to rewrite the **first** line (if empty, the second line otherwise), not add new lines to the end.

Comment: That almost solves my problem but it doesn't go to the next line it only types the next password_sentence right next to the first one on the first line

Comment: @WabbitEater, add `'\n'` to what you're writing then. That said, if this is what you want, why does your question talk about the "first line"?

Comment: @WabbitEater, the other thing is that if you didn't already have a `\n` after your last line, your file wasn't a valid UNIX text file in the first place. UNIX requires that all lines, including the last line of the file, have a newline at their end; and if you do that, you don't _need_ to add a starting newline when you add new content later. (This is unlike Windows, where newlines are separators instead of terminators)

Comment: I tried doing  file.write(password_sentence + '\n') but that didnt work

Comment: @WabbitEater, were you opening in append mode as this answer suggests when you tested that? And what do you mean by "didn't work"? If the program that _reads_ this file later can't deal with trailing newlines, that program is buggy (if it's supposed to process UNIX text files).

Comment: with open('/Users/benkollmar/Desktop/Projects/Passwords', 'a') as file:
    file.write(password_sentence + '\n')                                                                              This is what I wrote... sorry im pretty new to this

Comment: @WabbitEater, ...note that if you have a file already created by a previous version of your script that didn't add a trailing newline, the _first_ new thing you add will look wrong (because of the newline that's missing from the previous time the file was edited), but the second and later will be right.